# Sails.js: Create new record while associating w/ another new record with multi-tenants

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm using Sails.js 0.10.x. I'm referring to the functionality documented as ["Create new record while associating w/ another new record (REST)"](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Blueprint-API/Create.html) in combination with a multi-tenant system. All models have got a related_account as part of the primary key. And I need to find a bullet proof way to have it always filled with the current users related account.

In a parent-child relationship it is easy to fill the related_account on the parent by overriding the blueprint and simply setting the related_account property before the records are created. But as the javascript object is passed to Model.create(parent_and_children) it would mean that I would have to loop over all the children and set the related_account manually before creation. This work is tedious and error prone because there are a lot of situations where I need that. Furthermore this is a possible cause of critical defects as we work in a team and someone could forget to add it. In some cases the standard blueprints might be used, in other cases actions could be implemented manually.

**There must be a better way than always setting it manually.** Any idea is appreciated.

By the way: The value for the related_account is available in the request variable "user".

Comment: How did you implement the multi tenancy?

Comment: The related_account field always contains the account of the tenant.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help. I am doing the same where I need the companyId of the logged in users on every record (found in session.user.company.id). So this was my solution. It is a policy that checks if the model has any associations and then loops through those associations adding the companyId in the req.body object.

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

    req.options.where = _.assign({companyId : req.session.user.company.id}, req.options.where);

    var attachCompanyIdToBody = function(){
        if(_.isArray(req.body)){

        } else if (_.isObject(req.body)){
            req.body.companyId = req.session.user.company.id;
            attachCompanyIdToAssociations();    
        }
    };

    var attachCompanyIdToAssociations = function(){
        // Get assocations with current model
        var Model = actionUtil.parseModel(req);

        if(Model.associations){

            _.forEach(Model.associations, function(item,index,object){

                // if has company attached, remove company

                if(req.body[item.alias] && item.alias.toLowerCase() !== 'company'){
                    if(_.isArray(req.body[item.alias])){

                        // ToDo if assocation is a collection then loop through collection adding companyId

                    } else if(_.isObject(req.body[item.alias])){

                        // if assocation is object then add companyId to object

                        req.body[item.alias].companyId = req.session.user.company.id;

                    }
                }
            });
        }       
    };

    if(req.body){
        attachCompanyIdToBody();
    }

    return next();

};
```